# How does Subquery in select statement work in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, subquery

I have looked all over for an explanation, to how does the subquery in a select statement work and still I cannot grasp the concept because of very vague explanations.

I would like to know how do you use a subquery in a select statement in oracle and what exactly does it output.

For example, if i had a query that wanted to display the names of employees and the number of profiles they manage from these tables

Employee(EmpName, EmpId)

Profile(ProfileId, ..., EmpId)

how do I use the subquery?

I was thinking a subquery is needed in the select statement to implement the group by function to count the number of profiles being managed for each employee, but I am not too sure.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's simple-

```
SELECT empname,
       empid,
       (SELECT COUNT (profileid)
          FROM profile
         WHERE profile.empid = employee.empid)
           AS number_of_profiles
  FROM employee;
```

It is even simpler when you use a table join like this:

```
  SELECT e.empname, e.empid, COUNT (p.profileid) AS number_of_profiles
    FROM employee e LEFT JOIN profile p ON e.empid = p.empid
GROUP BY e.empname, e.empid;
```

---

**Explanation for the subquery:**

Essentially, a subquery in a `select` gets a scalar value and passes it to the main query. A subquery in `select` is not allowed to pass more than one row and more than one column, which is a restriction. Here, we are passing a `count` to the main query, which, as we know, would always be only a number- a scalar value. If a value is not found, the subquery returns `null` to the main query. Moreover, a subquery can access columns from the `from` clause of the main query, as shown in my query where `employee.empid` is passed from the outer query to the inner query.

---

*Edit*:

When you use a subquery in a `select` clause, Oracle essentially treats it as a left join (you can see this in the [explain plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231) for your query), with the cardinality of the rows being just one on the right for every row in the left.

---

**Explanation for the left join**

A left join is very handy, especially when you want to replace the `select` subquery due to its restrictions. There are no restrictions here on the number of rows of the tables in either side of the `LEFT JOIN` keyword.

For more information read [Oracle Docs on subqueries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries007.htm) and [left join or left outer join](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! this really helped. One question though. You said the subquery is not allowed to pass more than one column, so that means if I wanted to add a SUM function, I would have to use another subquery? or is it possible to have more than subquery in select?

Comment: Yes. You can use multiple subqueries in a select list. You will have to use another subquery for adding a SUM function.

Comment: Important, substituting a join for a subquery might cause a different result if there are several rows in the joined table that match. Good explanation on joins w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

In the Oracle RDBMS, it is possible to use a multi-row subquery in the select clause as long as the (sub-)output is encapsulated as a collection.  In particular, a multi-row select clause subquery can output each of its rows as an xmlelement that is encapsulated in an xmlforest.