# Oracle SQL: Selecting all, plus an extra column with a complex query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have these tables setup:
NOMINATIONS: A table of award nominations
NOMINATION_NOMINEES: A table of users with a FK on NOMINATIONS.ID

One Nomination can be referenced by many nominees via the ID field.

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(SELECT all records from NOMINATION_NOMINEES with this ID) AS "b" 
FROM NOMINATIONS a
LEFT JOIN NOMINATION_NOMINEES b on a.ID = b.ID
```

The results would look like:

> ID | NOMINATION_DESCRIPTION | ... | NUMBER_NOMINEES

Where NUMBER_NOMINEES is the number of rows in the NOMINATION_NOMINEES table with the current row's ID.

This is a tricky one, we are feeding this into a larger system so I'm hoping to get this in one query with a bunch of subqueries. Implementing subqueries into this has twisted my mind. Anyone have an idea of where to head with this?

I'm sure the above way is not close to a decent approach to this one, but I can't quite wrap my mind around this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a [single correlated sub-query in `SELECT` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557899/how-does-subquery-in-select-statement-work-in-oracle).

```
SELECT a.*, 
       ( SELECT COUNT(b.ID) FROM NOMINATION_NOMINEES b WHERE a.ID= b.ID )
FROM NOMINATIONS a
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `count` as an `analytic function`:

```
select a.*,
       count(b.id) over (partition by b.id) 
from nominations a
       left join nomination_nominees b on a.id = b.id
```